# .NET merge class library references

Tags: .net, ilmerge, fody-costura

I have a class library which contains WPF user control. This library has some dependencies but I want to deploy it as one assembly. As I know IlMerge has some problems with WPF. I tried Costura but it works only for applications, not for class libraries (as I have found out [here](http://code.google.com/p/costura/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=28)). Is there any way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As one of the contributors to Costura I can now confirm that it works for libraries as well as applications.

In fact all the unit tests for Costura are on a library, so it definitely works.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx). As I read somewhere, even the author of ILMerge tells that if he knew that way, ILMerge wouldn't exist.
Personally I've used it in WinForms project and it worked great, though it's [stated](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) that it handles WPF correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is already answered, but to fix the loading of assemblies using reflection you can attach the following code in the AssemblyLoad event

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"<path to your dll>");
var assemblyLoaderType = assembly.GetType("Costura.AssemblyLoader", false);
var attachMethod = assemblyLoaderType?.GetMethod("Attach", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
attachMethod?.Invoke(null, new object[] { });
```