# create a set of WPF user control into a single dll

Tags: wpf, user-controls

Just a simple and quick question. Is it possible, in WPF, to agregate some user controls I have created (they are dll) into a single DLL so our customers add one dll to the toolbox and they can access all our user components ???

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

You can try [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630), it merges multiple .NET assemblies into a single .NET assembly

Comment: It is not easy to use ILMerge with WPF stuff ..

[HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959893/net-merge-class-library-references) you can see a different approach 


I will give it a run but not sure if after merging like that the toolbox is going to add the different WPF user controls nicelly ...